# $X_n \overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} X$ and $X_n \overset{L^1}{\longrightarrow} Y$ implies $X = Y$ a.s.?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

If I have a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ such that
$$X_n \overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} X \quad\textrm{and}\quad X_n \overset{L^1}{\longrightarrow} Y$$
then is it always true that $X = Y$ a.s.? It certainly seems like it must be true. But if it is not always true, then what conditions must be imposed to make it true?

I feel like there must be an obvious proof, but I can't come up with it right off the bat. Can anyone give a pointer in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X_n \to Y$ in $L^1$ then there exist a subsequence that converges almost surely to $Y$. Since a.s. limits are unique up to a set of measure zero you have that $X=Y$ a.s.

Comment: Bingo. That was embarrassingly obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Without involving subsequences:

Note that $X_n \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} X \ \text{ and } \ X_n \xrightarrow{L^1} Y$ each imply convergence in probability. Thus, we have $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb P} X \ \textrm{ and } \ X_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb P} Y$. And we know that convergence in probability [is almost surely unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42137/51387), i.e. $X \stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{=} Y$.