# Concept of uniqueness of almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to show the following statement:

---

If $X_n \rightarrow Y_1$ in probability and $X_n \rightarrow Y_2$ in probability also. Then $Y_1 = Y_2$ almost surely.

---

Here is my approach:

I want to show $Y_1 = Y_2$ almost surely; so it is equivalent to show 
$$P(\{X_1 \neq X_2\}) =0$$

Hence, first observe the event 
$$\{\omega:Y_1(\omega) \neq Y_2(\omega)\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{\omega: |Y_1(\omega) - Y_2(\omega)| > \frac{1}{n}\}$$
Now, take probability on above equivalent events and since the event $\{|Y_1 - Y_2| > \frac{1}{n}\}$ is nonincreasing, we have 
$$P\{\omega:Y_1(\omega) \neq Y_2(\omega)\} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P\{|Y_1 - Y_2| > \frac{1}{n}\}$$
Then I stuck to conclude further to get the Right-Hand-Side limit becomes $0$. Any thought is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: $\{|Y_1 - Y_2| > 1/n\} \subset \{|Y_1 - X_n| > 2/n\} \cup \{|Y_2 - X_n| > 2/n\}$

Comment: Aram's hint should read $\{|Y_1 - Y_2| \gt 2/n\} \subset \{|Y_1 - X_k| \gt 1/n\} \cup \{|Y_2 - X_k| \gt 1/n\}$.

Comment: This is almost a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42075/limit-in-probability-is-almost-surely-unique). Namely, the question was different, but the accepted answer includes your case.